# peer node status command not working correcly in hyperledger fabric network

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric

I have a problem like this. I am very new to hyper ledger fabric. I attach a shell to a running peer container in visual studio code and hit peer node start command in that terminal it gives me an error saying that,

```
2018-09-13 09:08:04.621 UTC [nodeCmd] status -> INFO 040 Error trying to get status from local peer: rpc error: code = Unknown desc
= access denied
status:UNKNOWN
Error: Error trying to connect to local peer: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied
```

Can Someone help me to solve this problem? I search a lot but I was unable to find a solution to my problem. Thank You?

Answer (score 1):

**edit:** the problem is you are using an old card with a new setup. when you create the app and then restarted the environment, it leads to the regeneration of the certificates.

I guess the problem is the FABRIC_VERSION. When you set it to hlfv1 and get bash into peer container (`docker exec -it peer0.org1.example.com bash`), the peer commands are working properly but when you set it to hlfv12 there are some peer commands are not working. I guess there is something wrong with the startup scripts. There is no "creds" folder exists under hlfv12/composer like hlfv1/composer by the way..

Answer (score 0):

The `peer node status` command must be called by an administrator of the peer (someone who holds a private key matching one of the public keys in the MSP `admincerts` folder).

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `peer` commands on a properly configured (by correct authentication materials) client. In my case it was CLI node.

**Peer** node logs:

```
root@bba2c96e744e:/# peer node status
2019-04-04 13:26:18.407 UTC [nodeCmd] status -> INFO 001 Error trying to get status from local peer: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied
status:UNKNOWN 
Error: Error trying to connect to local peer: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied
root@bba2c96e744e:/# peer chaincode list --installed
Error: Bad response: 500 - access denied for [getinstalledchaincodes]: Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]
root@bba2c96e744e:/# peer logging getlevel system
Error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = access denied
```

**CLI** node logs:

```
root@4079f33980f3:/# peer node status
status:STARTED 
root@4079f33980f3:/# peer chaincode list --installed
Get installed chaincodes on peer:
Name: ccc, Version: 1.0, Path: chaincode/ccc, Id: e75e5770a29401d840b46a775854a1bb8576c6d83cf2832dce650d2a984ab29a
root@4079f33980f3:/# peer logging getlevel system
2019-04-04 13:26:02.287 UTC [cli/logging] getLevel -> INFO 001 Current log level for peer module 'system': INFO
```